# Finding tabs or 4 spaces (in C# code)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on formatting C# code in HTML. I'm trying to replace tabs/indents with 4 spaces.

Here's an example.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

I need to replace the tab before Response.Write with 4 spaces.

I tried things like ^\t, with different variations, tried ^\s\s\s\s. I thought this would be simple, but nothing I've tried seemed match the tabs.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

**Edit**

I copy directly from VS into TextBox1.

[image]

As you can see, there *are no* actual tabs (\t) in the TextBox value, which is the root of the problem. As noted in my comments, the spaces with ^ did work (for the first line only).

So my final regex will look like... this: "\s\s\s\s".

Comment: Try `\n\t` replaced with `\n    ` or check you have Multiline mode on in your Regex

Comment: What should happen with tabs in other places in the code? Left unchanged?

Comment: Is the tab always at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Yes - the tab should always be at the beginning (for now anyway), but we can forget that for a moment - plain "\t" doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\t+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
s = regex.Replace(s, m => new string(' ', 4 * m.Value.Length));
```

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/R54I8)

---

**Update**

Here's a version for ASP.NET Web Forms that runs in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="99px" Width="500px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string code = "protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)\n{\n\tResponse.Write(\"Hello World\");\n}";
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\t+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            TextBox1.Text = regex.Replace(code, m => new string('*', 4 * m.Value.Length));
        }
    }
}
```

Result after clicking button:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
****Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

The asterisks are there only to make it easy to see that the tabs have been replaced correctly with spaces. Change the `'*'` to `' '` to get spaces instead of asterisks.

Comment: @Rivka: Probably your compiler or editor settings. It does work, but note that it's using `"*"` instead of `" "` (so you can see the difference).

Comment: I'm copying/pasting straight from VS 2012 - doesn't work. I did notice in debugging mode, the value is "    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)\r\n    {\r\n        Response.Write(\"Hello World\");\r\n    }" (with 4 white spaces after the "\r\n"). When I substitute "\s\s\s\s" instead of "\t" it works for the first line.

Comment: @Rivka: Probably an editor misconfiguration or "helpful" plugin (do you use Resharper?) interfering with the copy+paste. Try reinstalling Visual Studio and it should work. I have a clean VS here and it works.

Comment: Reinstall VS? Seriously? No, I don't use Resharper. Edit: I'm actually using VWD 2010 - could that be it? When you copy you get "\t" in place of the tabs?

Comment: @Rivka: I'll try downloading and installing VWD 2010 Express and testing the code there.

Comment: What kind of Web Project are you doing? WebForms? MVC? Do you want this code to run when a page is requested?

Comment: WebForms - yes, on a postback. Thank you.

Comment: @Rivka: I just posted an update which I've copy+pasted from VWD 2010 Express. It's tested. It works. If it doesn't work for you then it's probably a problem with your VWD installation.

Comment: Are you aware that space isn't preserved in plain HTML?

Comment: Thanks, but the question is where are you getting that code value from? Did you manually input those tab chars? What about when you paste it into a multi-line textbox and get the value from there?

Comment: @Rivka: I just copy+pasted the text from ideone into VWD (notice it's exactly the same apart from the variable name). The input could just as easily come from a text box though.

Comment: Are you aware that the text you posted in your question doesn't actually contain any tab characters? It contains spaces, not tabs.

Comment: Exactly - that's why I'm asking where you pasted that code from - whered you get the ideone code from, bec when I paste directly from vwd, there are no tabs ( as I noted in a comment above.) I'll edit my Q later to clarify...

Comment: Thanks for your help! And I'm still curious if (if yes, how) you get that actual tab - "\t" when copying from VS.

Comment: @Rivka: There is a setting in Visual Studio on whether tabs or spaces should be inserted. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> Insert tabs/Keep spaces.

Comment: OK..but in VWD (where HTML isn't kept when copying) why would that make a difference - you paste it and you just have empty spaces; not "\s" or "\t". I think I'll resort to the fact that some things I just won't understand. Don't want to be bothersome :P

Comment: @Rivka: You might find it easier to understand if you enable "show whitespace" in Visual Studio. The keyboard shortcut chord is "Ctrl+R Ctr+W". Each space character shows up as a dot. Each tab character shows up as an arrow. Notice that (depending on your settings) when you press the Tab key either tabs or spaces might be inserted. I suspect this might be why you are confused. I nearly always have "show whitespace" enabled  (except when pair programming because it drives my colleagues crazy looking at all those dots).

Comment: Very helpful feature! That particular code which I was pasting into my TextBox had spaces before, not tabs. After I formatted it (Ctrl+K Ctrl+d), there were the tabs, and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "\tHello World";
string replacedTabWith4Spaces = text.Replace("\t", "    ");
```

Comment: This worked with the static "\t" but doesn't help in my case.